# MySQL Where Clause - get two cities where ID of 1. row < ID of 2. row

Tags: mysql, where-clause, rows, having

I have two tables:

1) table with travels

```
id | title
------------------------
 1 | travel1
 2 | travel2
 3 | travel3
```

2) table with cities

```
id | city      | travel_ID
------------------------
 1 | London    | 1
 2 | York      | 1
 3 | Newcastle | 1
 4 | London    | 2
 5 | Newcastle | 2
 6 | Newcastle | 3
 7 | York      | 3
```

id of the cities means also order.

so the question is: How can I get travels if cities (from A to B) are declared. (e.g. from York to Newcastle should get travel1, from London to Newcastle - travel1 and travel2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want travel ids where the id of the first city is less than the id of the second.

If so, then this may be what you are looking for:

```
select c1.travelid
from cities c1 join
     cities c2
     on c1.city = $CITY1 and
        c2.city = $CITY2 and
        c1.travelid = c2.travelid and
        c1.id < c2.id;
```

If you want the name, you can just join that in:

```
select t.*
from travels t join
     cities c1
     on c1.travelid = t.travelid join
     cities c2
     on c1.city = $CITY1 and
        c2.city = $CITY2 and
        c1.travelid = c2.travelid and
        c1.id < c2.id;
```